# PHPStorm Vagrant Menu not working

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm

I have installed PHPStorm 7.1 on my Mac and I have a project with Vagrant already setup in it with its own .sh file to bootstrap it.

Problem is, `vagrant up` works in the Terminal but using Tools -> Vagrant -> Up comes up with a blank task panel and doesn't boot up the instance...

Why does `vagrant up` work but PHPStorm's Vagrant menu doesn't?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it.

I reinstalled OS X by running the repair disk and I also updated Vagrant to the latest version.

This seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you select tools->Vagrant->Up and you get:

```
/usr/bin/vagrant up

Process finished with exit code 0
```

using the latest version of PHP storm (7.1.2)?

Then need to **provision**.

Running up to an already built and running box  (I presume in your case) wont have any effect.

Select provision to run **Vagrant provisioning**

Vagrant on the first up automatically provisions. On the second up, no provisioning takes place.

Also look in preferences for the Vagrant configuration. Set your prefs there

more about phpstorm [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/10/phpstorm-7-0-released-php-5-5-vagrant-ssh-console-debugger-config-validation-drupal-frameworks-more/) and docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/vagrant.html)

Comment: Jimmy is right. I was having the same problem and provisioning fixed it. Go to Tool->Vagrant->Up to start the Vagrant VM. Then go to Tools->Vagrant->Provision. Once that exits with a 0, try starting an SSH session with the VM: Tools->Start SSH Session.Choose the Vagrant VM in the pop-up dialog.

Comment: This solution isn't working. Vagrant Up takes absolutely forever to load and it still doesn't load up even after provisioning.

Comment: @Jamesking56 can you elaborate on your problems? What is the console saying? Is it loading? Is there CPU activity?

Comment: The console isn't showing anything, just says `Process finished with exit code 0`. It works in iTerm but not in PHPStorm

Comment: @Jamesking56 if you press provision? Maybe the provisioning is already done ok. Vagrant via php storm does not post output.

Comment: I have fixed it, see new answer.